# How to delete the data in Ruby on rails CRUD operation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I delete the data in Ruby on rails. I am new in ruby on rails and I am following the tutorails on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
But the delete opration is not working it redirects to the article. 
Article controller:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to article_path
end
```

Index page:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
             method: :delete,
             data: { confirm: 'Are You sure?' } %>
```

I am useing ruby version 2.2.4-p230 and rails version 4.2.6 and mysql database.

Comment: Does the record gets deleted in the db?

Comment: When you say redirects to the article do you mean the Article show method of the article you're trying to delete?

Comment: I think your **link_to** is taking you to the **show** action instead of **destroy** action. In order to confirm this you can check your server log. Another question, are you trying this in an Windows machine ??

Comment: @Meshpi yes it redirect to show method of article which I am trying to delete

Comment: Can you check your routes.rb file to see if it has 'resources :articles'?

Comment: @Meshpi yes it has the resources :articles I have also checked it by rake routes command

Comment: It looks to me as if your jQuery/jquery ujs is not getting loaded due to which data-mthod=delete is not being properly operated.

Comment: I don't believe nobody has ever rectified this??? I am having the identical issue and Googling it just brings me here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm the code look correct.This might be the JavaScript issue in application.js
Just install the node.js or update if already installed. then restart the server. It will solve the issue if the error is in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the typo..

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
             method: :delete,
             data: { confirm: 'Are You sure?' } %>
```

Comment: yes I have tried, I can update and insert the new record by I am not able to delete it

Comment: It does not gives any error. It just redirects to the show page of the article which I want to delete.

Comment: Yes can you see the data still exists in the index page. It is redirected because you called `redirect_to article_path`. It is running the code here.